# How to get the response headers in dojo/store/JsonRest?

Tags: javascript, dojo, jsonreststore, dojo.xhrget

I’m using `dojo/store/JsonRest` to fetch for some data. But I also need the response headers. How can I access them?

```
this.transport = new JsonRest({
  target: "my/target"
});

this.transport.query({}).then(function(resp) {
  debugger; // <- I want to get the response headers here!
})
```

I tried accessing it by using the `this` keyword within the function at debugger time. But that is just the window object.

Is that even possible?

Comment: You are getting the window object in `this` because there is no context of the `.then` function. If you want to get the `this.transport` as `this` in the `.then` function then use `lang.hitch` -> `this.transport.query({}).then(lang.hitch(this.transport, function(resp) { //here this is this.transport} );`
On another note, to get the response headers, you would have to either dig in the code of JsonRest or send the XHR using the `dojo.xhr` module.

Comment: use `.bind()` to set the scope of you function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/store/JsonRest` by itself do not provide a way to get the headers, but here is an example of how you can get all or individual headers.

```
var transport = new JsonRest({
  target: "my/target"
});

var result = transport.query({});

result.then(function(resp) {
  var localXHR = result.ioArgs.xhr;

  // get all headers, return an String
  console.log(localXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());

  // get one header
  console.log(localXHR.getResponseHeader('content-type'));

  // do something with the response
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Hope it helps